# Output reads " 13test.sh: line 5: [: missing `]' " but adding brackets then directs the error to a nested if statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

The goal is to take line of usernames and then run the w command on it if it matches the who search or say that the person is not online otherwise.

```
read -p "Enter User ID's: " str

for i in [ $str ]; 
do
    if [ who -u | grep -q $i ];
    then
        echo $i
        w -u $i 
    else
        echo $i
        echo user is not logged in
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Use `for id in $str` instead of `for i in [ $str ];` and `if who -u | grep -q "$id"` instead of `if [ who -u | grep -q $i ];`.

- The stuff inside `[ … ]` is a [*conditional expression*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29), which is different from a command.
- `[ … ]` doesn't *print* anything, so the `for` loop doesn't have anything to work with if you wrap `$str` in it.
- `if COMMAND` is the canonical way of running something if a command succeeds.
- Single letter variables are a Bad Idea™ for maintainability reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The error was somewhat ambiguous and threw me off.

Comment: If this worked, please consider marking the answer as accepted.